# Signed Distance Function - 3D Plane

Tags: glsl, distance, fragment-shader

I truly love IQ's page and the information within regarding SDF's:
(https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm)

I have a few figured out but but his sdPlane is getting me..

```
float sdPlane( vec3 p, vec4 n )
{
  // n must be normalized
  return dot(p,n.xyz) + n.w;
}
```

He doesn't identify what the input 'n' is being used for and I am not the greatest in math.
Something like the Width, Height, Depth from point p, but then n.w doesn't make sense..

Any help will be awesome, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n` is a [Plane Equation](http://www.songho.ca/math/plane/plane.html). `.xyz` is the normal vector of the plane and `.w` is the distance from origin.

Comment: Ahh... Okay.. so point p and normalized point n.  That's why messing with n will change it's direction.  That makes sense now.. Thanks!  I was trying to figure out how to constrict the plane like the side of a box, I forgot that a plane extends in all directions infinatly.